# Javascript/jQuery set a time delay, pop off bottom element from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `$.each()` loop in a jQuery AJAX call. For each element in my response data, I want to prepend a segment of HTML to a container class in my index.html file.

You can view the code below as a [codepen here](https://codepen.io/danielschnoll/pen/rNabBME), since mobile formatting is bad and this likely didn't paste properly

```
$.each(responseData, function(i, item) {
    /*
    if(i > 4){
        $($("section").last()).remove();
    }
    */
    try{
        username = item.user.name;
        user_text = item.text;
        imgURL = item.user.profile_image_url;
        hashtags = item.entities.hashtags;
        let hashtagsDiv = ""
        if(hashtags.length > 0){
            hashtagsDiv = "<div class='row'><div class='col s10 offset-s2'>HASHTAGS: "
            for(i = 0; i < hashtags.length; i++){
                hashtagsDiv += "#"+hashtags[i].text+"; ";
            }
            hashtagsDiv += "</div></div>"
        }
        $("<div class ='row'>\
            <div class ='col s12'>\
                <section class='card-panel grey lighten-5 z-depth-1'>\
                    <div class='row valign-wrapper'>\
                        <div class='col s2'>\
                            <img src=\"" + imgURL + "\" alt='profile_pic' class='circle responsive-img'>\
                        </div>\
                        <div class='col s10'>\
                            <span class='black-text'> @" + username + " says: " + user_text + "</span>\
                        </div>\
                    </div>\
                    " + hashtagsDiv + "\
                </section>\
            </div>\
        </div>").prependTo(".container").slideDown();
        $(function(){  
            window.setTimeout(5000);
        });
    }  
    catch(err){
        console.log("ERROR: " + err.message);
    }
});
```

The `.container` in the `prependTo()` is a class from a `<section>` tag in my HTML file. The `prependTo()` works just fine, and when I reload my webpage I see the last element at the top of the page. Basically the expected behavior is that this acts like a queue, so the first element goes to the bottom, the second stacks on top of it, etc etc until I reach the end of the requested JSON, and the last element sits on top.

Currently I have two issues right now:

1. The `setTimeout()` doesn't work. All elements come in at once, and I
   can't seem to figure out how to put a delay on each iteration. This should work in conjunction with my `slideDown()` call. Every few seconds, slideDown the next element.
2. Once the counter `i > 4`, I want to remove the last element from the DOM each iteration. This will keep at most 5 elements on screen, and every cycle we pop off the last, or oldest, one from the bottom of the queue. I can't seem to figure this part out either. If I were to uncomment the `if` block at the top of the `$.each()` loop, nothing shows up on screen.

If someone could address these two issues that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: you might want to reduce the code to 10, 15 lines or less for other users to debug... right now your `setTimeout` doesn't use the form `setTimeout(function() { }, 5000)` which is what should be used. So you should wrap everything you want to do 5 seconds later in that function above

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a minimal working example of your problem? It's easier to work on that and see the problem directly.

Comment: Hello, does my answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59929302/9060223) help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to remove in `$($("section").last()).remove()`, but I'm assuming that you're trying to remove the newly inserted `div`, in which case you shouldn't have selected `section`. Assuming that all `responseData` is delivered before running the function, I've created this solution below. I've also set the time of which new `row`s are prepended to 1000ms.

What you want to do is basically wrap your `setTimeout` outside the prepending function and set the time to increase per index. I really recommend reading **all** the explanation provided [in this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to understand clearly about `setTimeout`.

Here's the minimal working example:

```js
let responseData = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

$.each(responseData, function(i, item) {
  setTimeout(function() {
      try {
        $(`<section>Section Number ${i}</section>`)
          .prependTo(".container")
          .slideDown();
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + err.message);
      }
      
      if (i > 4) {
        console.log(i)
        $("section").last().remove()
      }
  }, i * 1000)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "container"></div>
```